# program running on IDLE but not through command line

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my code , let us call it  "example.py"

```
import traceback
import sys
import os
import linecache


try:
    data_files = [x[2] for x in os.walk(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))]
    fileNameList = data_files[0]    # gets the list of files in the directory where example.py is present
    execfile("sample.py")

except:
```

this program works perfectly when I run it through IDLE but gives me the following error when I run it through the command line

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 15, in <module>
    fileNameList = data_files[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I can only assume it cannot get the list of files in the folder from the command line , I am new to python programming so I would be truly grateful if someone could solve this or atleast point where I am going wrong

Comment: What command are you using to call it from the command line? Are you doing `python example.py folder`?

Comment: Also, why do you have an `except` statement, and why is it the last line (where is the except block?)

Comment: check value of sys.argv[0]

Comment: @DavidRobinson : I get my command line to the folder containing the file and then 'python example.py'

Comment: the except block has some exceptions , I did not put it up as they do not pertain to the problem

Comment: @joaquin print sys.argv[0] prints out example.py

Comment: Seems to me like you could have figured out what was wrong here yourself by printing out the value of `sys.argv[0]` and running the script both ways and seeing the difference. Your question might then be what to do to make it work in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

You should do:

```
data_files = [x[2] for x in os.walk(os.getcwd())]
```

The problem is that when you run it from the command line `sys.argv[0]` is just the name you used to call the file (`example.py`), *not* the full absolute path to the file (which is what IDLE uses). Thus, `os.path.dirname` won't get anything from it.

Note that if you run the file from a different directory, like:

```
python ../my_examples/example.py
```

This script will iterate over the directory you are *currently* in, *not* the directory that `example.py` is in. If you want to use the directory `example.py` is in, you could do:

```
data_files = [x[2] for x in os.walk(os.path.abspath(__file__))]
```

Comment: `os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])` would also work because it returns the current directory when `sys.argvp[0]` is the empty string, as it is when the script is run from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is this: When you run from IDLE `sys.argv[0]` holds the entire path to your script, so `os.path.dirname()` extracts the dirname correctly. But when you run from the command line, `sys.argv[0]` holds only the script name, like `example.py`, not path, so `os.path.dirname()` returns an empty string, which, in turn, when fed to `walk` doesn't give anything meaningful.

**Edit**

How to fix: Instead of using `sys.argv[0]` alone, use `os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])` to get the full path of your script. Then `os.path.dirname()` applied to *that* will give you the dir name, and work on both IDLE and command line.

Comment: @martineau - There! I suggested a fix.. ;-)

Comment: Your fix makes it work in both IDLE and from the command line, so I up-voted as promised. However what you say about the contents of `sys.argv[0]` when it's run from the command-line is wrong -- it's empty not the script's name. Your fix works anyway because `os.path.abspath('')` returns the current directory.

Comment: @martineau - first, let me thank you for keeping your promise. Second, it's the first time I meet someone who encourages people to improve in order to help others, I'm impressed. I'm sure you made a very good software manager at one point or another. Last, regarding this code, I didn't exactly understand what you said. I think you meant that this relates more to Python knowing what the current directory is, rather than `path` handling. So, I believe instead of using `os.path.dirname()` it would be enough to do simply `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Not really. My original point was simply that while you seemed to be telling the OP what was wrong which was "atleast" what they wanted, what they really were looking for was a solution -- meaning something that would work both in IDLE and from the command-line. After you added your Edit, I decided to check it out to see if it actually worked before up-voting it. While doing this I noticed that what you said was wrong wasn't entirely correct. However, as I also mentioned, the solution in your edit worked nonetheless. Guess the lesson here is to always **test your code** before posting.